# Override authenticate method of symfony2 authentification provider

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using fosuserbundle, in login process the system automatically check if the credentials are correct then authenticate the user. But i dont want the user to be authenticated unless a user field has a certain value in the database.
For this i think i need to override the authenticate method of the Authentication Provider to check that user value.
Would this be correct and what is the best way to do it ?
Thank you

Comment: we have overwritten `onAuthenticationSuccess` in an extended `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` - before returning the response we did our stuff e.g. checking for additional conditions.

Comment: LBA This function is called after authentificating the user which is not what i want. I need to intervene in the authenticate function

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `isEnabled()` function of your user entity to fit your needs:

```
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->enabled && ('my_value_ok_for_login' === $this->getMyField());
}
```

Comment: Thanks COiL for your answer but this will still authenticate user while i dont want to

Comment: No it won't, a not enabled user can't login.

Comment: But this way the message "user is not enabled" Will be displayed when in fact i want a different behavior which is to send an email to the user and display the login form again with a special error message

Comment: So look at the events like LBA told you: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php

Comment: Fosuserbundle doesnt provide the necessary event because the authentification is done by symfony security authentification provider

Comment: Look at the authentication doc then: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html